# Applying wrapper to a function brakes it

Tags: python, decorator, wrapper, python-decorators

I'm trying to create wrapper. My code works with simple example function, but when I apply it to example function, it stops working.

Code of my wrapper:

```
import functools
import time
from functools import wraps

def profiler(func):
          
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        setattr(func, 'calls', 0)
        t1 = time.monotonic() # what's time at the beginning of run
        func(*args, **kwds)
        func.calls += 1 # add 1 to number of calls
        t2 = time.monotonic() # what's time at the beginning of run
        last_time_taken = t2 - t1
        setattr(wrapper, 'last_time_taken', last_time_taken)
        setattr(wrapper, 'calls', func.calls)
    return wrapper
```

I would be glad to get any advice helping to solve this error. Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrapper doesn't return, which is the same as returning `None`. When you call the decorated function, you will in practice just run the wrapper.

Make sure the wrapper returns the result of your function and it will work just fine.

```
import functools
import time
from functools import wraps

def profiler(func):
          
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        setattr(func, 'calls', 0)
        t1 = time.monotonic() # what's time at the beginning of run
        res = func(*args, **kwds)
        func.calls += 1 # add 1 to number of calls
        t2 = time.monotonic() # what's time at the beginning of run
        last_time_taken = t2 - t1
        setattr(wrapper, 'last_time_taken', last_time_taken)
        setattr(wrapper, 'calls', func.calls)
        return res
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Yeah, it was the root of the problem. Thanks for your help, problem is solved!